# Favorite Fruit, Flower, Leaf For Durga Maa & Kali Maa

Tags: durga, puja, kali

Googled this several times in the past and again recently. Is it always red hibiscus for flower in puja ?

Could someone tell me which is best fruit to offer for Devi Maa

Thx

Comment: AFAIK it's Pomegranate, Hibiscus and Bilva leaves for both of them. I don't know about it's scriptural authenticity though. Sorry for that. 

Comment: @LSSJBroly  Pomegranate, I am huge fan of those. Thx so much ! 